# How to access a specific string from pickle loaded file?

Tags: python, pickle

I have an array of model pickle files I'm loading into a new variable within a for loop, and I'm able to print out all of the data contained in each pickle file. How would I access a specific string in the loaded pickle file data?

Code:

```
 model_files=["models/Model_1.pkl", "models/Model_2.pkl", "models/Model_3.pkl", \
              "models/Model_4.pkl", "models/Model_5.pkl", "models/Model_6.pkl"]

for i in range(len(model_files)):
    infile = open(model_files[i], 'rb')
    model = pickle.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    print(model)
```

`print(model)` output for 1 pickle file:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
               intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
               multi_class='warn', n_jobs=None, penalty='l1',
               random_state=1222, solver='warn', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
               warm_start=False)
```

I want to access the `"LogisticRegression"` string.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from what's in your question what `model` is exactly. Please [edit] your question and provide more details.

Comment: Model is the new var I’m loading the pickle file contents in.

Comment: That's obvious, what we need to know is what _kind_ of variable  `model` is — what's its type? This is extremely important to know in order to answer your question. It doesn't look like a string, it's looks more like it might be an instance of some undefined class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(model_files)):
    infile = open(model_files[i], 'rb')
    model = pickle.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    print(type(model).__name__)
```

This will give you class names and in this case `'LogisticRegression'`